# Exchange Custom Attributes Excemptions

Tags: exchange, powershell-v3.0

I am trying to create a scenario by which a resource mailbox is hidden from all users unless specified. I have found the following article that i have used to hide the resource box;

http://www.mustbegeek.com/configure-address-lists-in-exchange-server-2013/

Does anyone know how to exempt the address list policy for certain users?

Thanks

Comment: You don't exempt, you enforce another address policy with the AD attribute. Like I do often link policy to the compagny name, when a server host multiple domain, and the policy enforce the correct alias.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. I will test and revert back.